# PHP : Must login twice until session variables are set

Tags: php, html, forms, session, authentication

SOLUTION: after many hours of searching, it seems this problem was occurring when I access my website without adding the "www." before the domain. so what actually was happening is, I was logging in with example.com/login.php sets session somewhere, that my member control doesn't recognize, so it redirects me back to www.example.com/login.php, that when I login everything works Ok.

when I login from www.example.com/login.php (with the www.) it logs in correctly from first attemp.

So I added a code to make sure I always have the www in the URL:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "example.com")
{
   $url = "http://www." . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   header("Location: $url");
}
```

and everything works well now. Hope it helps someone.

---

So, I have built over 3 websites, and all have same problem, I don't know why, I have to login twice till I'm rly logged in.. (till the session variables are set). Help is really appreciated, been trying to fix this and looking for solution since a long time...

```
    session_start();
if ((isset($_SESSION['UserName']))&&(isset($_SESSION['LastActivity'])))
{
   header ('Location: http://www.example.com/Account.php');
}

if (isset($_POST['username']))
{
    mysql_connect("localhost","DBuser","pass") or 
    die ("could not connect to mysql");
    mysql_select_db("DBNAME") or die ("no database");

    $inputUserName = $_POST['username'];
    $inputPass = $_POST['password'];

    $datausername = mysql_real_escape_string($inputUserName);
    $password=md5($inputPass);

    $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM Members 
    WHERE UserName='$datausername' AND 
    Password='$password'";

    $result = mysql_query($sqlCommand);


    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
       $_SESSION['UserName'] = $datausername;

       $_SESSION['LastActivity']= time();
       sleep(2);
       $LoginDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

       mysql_connect("localhost","DBUPDATEusername","DBuserPass") or 
    die ("could not connect to mysql");
    mysql_select_db("databaseName") or die ("no database");   

       mysql_query("Update Members SET LastLogin='$LoginDate' WHERE 
            UserName='$datausername'");

       mysql_close(); 
       echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://www.example.com/Account.php?p=Login_Success"/>';
    }
    else {
        mysql_close();
        echo '<div id="error_msg">Error: Information entered are not correct. Please check and try again.</div>';}
    }

}
?>
<form...
```

login form (with action=""), and method post).

Note: I use the html refresh tag, because I can't use the header redirect.. (I get error that header is already sent).

and in the example.com/Account.php I do this check at the top of the code:

```
  session_start();
if ((!isset($_SESSION['UserName']))||(!isset($_SESSION['LastActivity'])))
{
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/?p=Must_Login');
}
```

And and it seems that first time I login and am redirected to account.php panel.. the session values are not set, and redirects me back to Must_Login page. I login again (same login page I use at first time. But the second time when I login, it does set the session values, and everything is OK.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: It seems your `mysql_connect()` is missing before your first `mysql_query()`. And you should really work on your code. You are assigning variables which you don't use...

Comment: You should look into replacing the mysql_ functions with MySQLi or PDO, MySQL functions have been deprecated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOLUTION: after many hours of searching, it seems this problem was occurring when I access my website without adding the "www." before the domain. so what actually was happening is, I was logging in with mydomain.com/login.php sets session somewhere, that my member control doesn't recognize, so it redirects me back to www.mydomain.com/login.php, that when I login everything works Ok.

when I login from www.mydomain.com/login.php (with the www.) it logs in correctly from first attemp.

So I added a code to make sure I always have the www in the URL:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "mydomain.com")
{
   $url = "http://www." . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   header("Location: $url");
}
```

and everything works well now. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This pointed me in the correct direction. I was seeing this behavior on just one page. I had accidentally included the www. on a link. Thanks for some insight.

Comment: Such a lifesaver this finnally got my script working

Comment: @shadyhossin, Thank you. This fix the issue I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to database before your Members select.

Comment: Ofcourse I did that, I didn't include it in the code sorry, editing now

Comment: Updated post with problem/solution.

Answer (score 0):

Start session if it has not been started yet.
Connect to the server and select the database before querying.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
      session_start();
}

mysql_connect("localhost","DBusername","DBuserPass") or 
    die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db("databaseName") or 
    die ("no database");  

if ((isset($_SESSION['UserName']))&&(isset($_SESSION['LastActivity'])))
       header ('Location: http://www.mysite.com/Account.php');

if (isset($_POST['username']))
{

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    $sqlCommand = sprintf( "SELECT * FROM Members 
    WHERE UserName = %s AND Password = %s", mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['username'] ), md5( $_POST['password'] ) );

    $result = mysql_query( $sqlCommand );

    $rowsnr = mysql_num_rows( $result );

    if (mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0)
    {
       $_SESSION['UserName'] = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['username'] );

       $_SESSION['LastActivity']= time();
       sleep(2);      

       mysql_query(sprintf("UPDATE Members SET LastLogin = NOW() WHERE 
            UserName = %s", mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['username'] )));

       mysql_close(); 

       echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://www.mysite.com/Account.php?p=Login_Success"/>';
    }
    else 
    {
        mysql_close();
        echo '<div id="error_msg">Error: Information entered are not correct. Please check and try again.</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting following code AFTER you check for the login?

```
session_start();

if ((!isset($_SESSION['UserName']))||(!isset($_SESSION['LastActivity'])))
{
    header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/?p=Must_Login');
}
```

Comment: Within the page the session variables are set, when I redirect they are lost.

Answer (score 0):

PHP sessions are written to the session handler after the script which started the session finishes execution. In your case the first script started the session and updated session variables 'username' and 'lastactivity' then redirected to another page. But still the session values are in memory - not registered to be used in the second script.

One way to fix the problem is to call

```
session_write_close();
```

before (or after) `sleep(2)`;

for more information see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

Comment: Oh, this does make sense, I will try it and post back if worked, thank you very much

Comment: This was not the problem, I posted the problem up in my post, thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 0):

try `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com')` before your session_start();

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, in my case I was redirecting to the website address after login:

```
header('Location: http://mywebsite.com');
die();
```

Even manually closing the session before the redirect didn't help.

I fixed it by instead redirecting to a specific page:

```
header('Location: index.php');
die();
```