# PHP Login system being weird

Tags: php, html

Okay, im am making a boy scout website for a local troop. I made the login system and for some reason it is making me login in twice before displaying the login page. Please help me figure out why it is doing this. when i login i have to reload, then it will display the information

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
     <h1 id="title">Welcome to Boy Scout Troop 416, ----------- -------</h1>

    <div id="left">
        <section class="part">
            <h1>About Us</h1>
            <p>Hello, we are Boy Scout Troop 416. Our Scout Master is       Mr. Kelly Barrett. We have camp-outs about once a mouth and our meetings are every Tuesday      at 7:00.</p>
        </section>

        <section class="part">
            <h1>FAQ</h1>
            <h2>When and Where are the Meetings?</h2>
            <p>The meetings are every Tuesday at The Williamsburg American Legion, Post 288 on Main Street from 7:00 to 8:30.</p>
            <h2>How do I sign up?</h2>
            <p>To sign up you can go to "Contact Information", and contact the Scout Master and tell him you want to join then, he will help you with the rest.</p>
            <h2>How much Does it cost?</h2>
            <p>To sign up it is about____. Every camp-out is about $3.00 for food. The uniforms are about____.</p>
            <h2>What will you learn?</h2>
            <p>You will learn how to use a:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Knife</li>
                <li>Compass</li>
                <li>Bow and Arrow</li>
                <li>Axe</li>
                <li>Hatchet</li>
                <li>And much more!</li>
            </ul>
            <p>You will learn how to:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Tie different kinds of knots</li>
                <li>Put up a tent</li>
                <li>Cook</li>
                <li>Treat a hurt person</li>
                <li>And a lot more!</li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div id="middle">
        <?php
        require 'connect.inc.php';
        session_start();

        function getuserfield($field) {
            $query = "SELECT `$field` FROM `users` WHERE      `id`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
            if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
                if ($query_result = mysql_result($query_run, 0,   $field)) {
                    return $query_result;
                }       
            }
        }
        ?>

        <section class="part">
            <h1>Announcements</h1>
            <p>bla f gg keggnfm gw lorem isput g fgrh egyhe tryher t.   </p>
            <div class="div"></div>
            <p>Need help with merit badges, try <a href="http://meritbadge.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page" target="_blank">Meritbadge.org</a>.</p>
        </section>

        <section class="part">
            <h1>Upcoming Events</h1>
            <table class="table" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="0px">
                <tr>
                    <th>Events</th><th>Location</th>  <th>Date</th><th>Time</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Camp-out</td><td>A Place</td><td>11/11/11</td><td>5:30pm</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Camp-out</td><td>A Place</td><td>11/11/11</td><td>5:30pm</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Camp-out</td><td>A Place</td><td>11/11/11</td><td>5:30pm</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </section>

        <section class="part">
            <h1>Contact Info.</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><img class="img_contact" src="pictures/person.png" /></td><td>Rick Shoe</td><td>email@example.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img class="img_contact" src="pictures/person2.png" /></td><td>Raymond Kneipp jr.</td><td>email@example.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img class="img_contact" src="pictures/person3.png" /></td><td>Bobby Star</td><td>email@example.com</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div id="right">

        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        echo '
            <section class="part">
                <h1>Account</h1>
                <p>Account Balance: '.getuserfield('money').'</p>
                <p>Rank: '.getuserfield('rank').'</p>
                <p><a href="logout.php"><button>Logout</button></a></p>
            </section>
            ';

        echo '
            <section class="part">
                <form action="index.php" method="POST">
                    <h1>Edit Account</h1>
                    <p>Password: <input type="password" name="" maxlength="50" /></p>
                    <p>New Password: <input type="newPassword2" name="" maxlength="50" /></p>
                    <p>New Password: <input type="newPassword" name="" maxlength="50" /></p>
                    <p><a href="logout.php"><button>Logout</button></a></p>
                </form>
            </section>
            ';

        } else {
        ?>
        <section class="part">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <form action="index.php" method="POST">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username:</td><td><input type="email" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['remember'])) { echo $_COOKIE['remember']; } ?>" maxlength="50"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="50"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Remember Me<input type="checkbox" value="remember" /></td><td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <?php

                            if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
                                $username = $_POST['username'];
                                $password = $_POST['password'];
                                $password_hash = md5($password);
                                if (!empty($password) && !empty($username)) {
                                    if (strlen($username) <= 50 && strlen($username) >= 5 && strlen($password) <= 50 && strlen($password) >= 5) {
                                        $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password_hash'";
                                        $query_run = mysql_query($query);
                                        if (mysql_num_rows($query_run) == 0) {
                                            echo 'Username or Password is incorrect.';
                                        } else if (mysql_num_rows($query_run) == 1) {
                                            $user_id = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'id');
                                            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                                            if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
                                                setcookie('remember', $username, time()+86400);
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            echo 'Username or Password is incorrect.';
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        echo 'Password or username is too long or too short.';
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    echo 'All fields required';
                                }
                            }

                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </section>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

        <section class="part">
            <h1>Photos</h1>
            <a href="gallery.php"><img class="slide_img" src="pictures/fall.jpg" /></a>
            <div id="play_menu">
                <button id="back">◄</button>
                <button id="go">►</button>
            </div>
            <h2><a href="gallery.php">Click to Browse Gallery</a></h2>
        </section>

        <section class="part">
            <h1>Share</h1>
            <p>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/DBCTroop416" target="_blank"><img class="share" src="pictures/fb.png" /></a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img class="share" src="pictures/t.png" /></a>
                <a href="http://instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img class="share" src="pictures/ig.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/" target="_blank"><img class="share" src="pictures/p.png" /></a>
            </p>
        </section>

        <section class="part">
            <h1>Scout Rules</h1>
            <div class="center">
            <h2>Pledge of Allegiance</h2>
            <p>"I pledge allegiance to the Flag of the United States of America, and to the Republic for which it stands, one Nation under God, indivisible, with liberty and justice for all."</p>
            <h2>Scout Law</h2>
            <p>"A scout is trustworthy, loyal, helpful, friendly, courteous, kind, obedient, cheerful, thrifty, brave, clean, and reverent."</p>
            <h2>Scout Oath</h2>
            <p>"On my honor I will do my best To do my duty to God and my country and to obey the Scout Law; To help other people at all times; To keep myself Physically strong, mentally awake, and morally straight."</p>
            <h2>Scout Motto</h2>
            <p>"Be Prepared."</p>
            <h2>Scout Slogan</h2>
            <p>"Do a Good Turn daily."</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

<footer id="foot">
    <p>Version: 3.0.0</p>
    <p>This website is hosted, managed, and was created by:</p>
    <h1><a href="#">Biz Name</a></h1>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do scouts know about sql injections?

Comment: Damn, do I really have to look at these codes? its ugly and its hurting my eyes!!  :( QQ, you can start by separating php and html :)

Comment: Is `session_start();` inside `connect.inc.php` also and all other files included? Plus you shouldn't be storing password with `md5`

Comment: You also have a lot of `name=""` (empty/unnamed) which might be "one" of the causes.

Comment: yes, im going to work on security after I get it to function right.

Comment: some name="" are blank because I did not make that part yet, it should not afect anything

Comment: Why should I not store passwords as md5's?

Comment: md5 is old school. That will be hacked and cracked in no time. Use sha2.

Comment: so just change all md5's with sha2

Comment: Have a look here and look in the comments .... http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Comment: how would i separate my html and php

Comment: sha2(); is not working, but sha1(); is, should i use that?

Comment: When I log in incorrect, after that I have to log in twice

Comment: How did I know , when you said you wrote your own user system and then had a basic problem with it, that your system would be written with outdated mysql functions and ALSO vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: what mysql funtions are out of date, what should i replace them with

Comment: when i login i have to reload, then it will display the information

Answer (score 0):

session_start needs to be up top just under your doctype declaration.

[PHP : Must login twice until session variables are set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960811/php-must-login-twice-until-session-variables-are-set)

You might look into this discussion also.

Comment: the page is still making me login twice before i can access anything

Comment: why should it be under `doctype` declaration ?

Comment: To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser. <-- From php manual. Also, I put it high in the doc so that I can see it easily.

Comment: It needs to be before ANY output, and that includes the doctype declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it logs in eventually at all - you're outputting a ton of data before evaluating the results of the postback, meaning the `setcookie` call should fail since headers have already been sent. It could accidentally work because of implicit output buffering.

The true problem is of course that you're outputting the entire login form before even checking postback data, and *after* outputting conditional data. Your code is executed sequentially, and if you consider that it's obvious that your code can't work.

You should always evaluate postbacks at the *top* of your code, before any data is generated, and if state is changed on a POST best practice is to issue a 303 redirect to yourself to get rid of the F5'able errors, for example:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
  // Check login stuffs, and if succesful redirect
  if($succesfully_logged_in)
  {
    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See other');
    header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    die;
  }
}

?><!doctype html> ...and the rest of your code...
```

Comment: should i add the "die()" function at the end of the if's, like you did?

Comment: @RaymondKneipp, use PHPass for encryption, use PDO for database connections and use prepared statements! And separate PHP code from HTML as possible.

Comment: @RaymondKneipp yes, the `die` stops output and ensures the redirect is handled right away.